# display tr tags based on first array count and compare with second array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, forms, loops, checkbox

I have two arrays. I want to display the `tr` tag based on the count of `$daterange` and inside this, I need to check the `date` value with the `second array` `date` value.

First array :

```
$daterange = ['01/10/2017','02/10/2017','03/10/2017','04/10/2017','05/10/2017'];
```

Second array :

```
$job = [0 => ['id' =>1,'date' => '03/10/2017'],
        1 => ['id' =>2,'date' => '12/10/2017'],
        2 => ['id' =>3,'date' => '14/10/2017'],
        3 => ['id' =>4,'date' => '13/10/2017'],
        4 => ['id' =>5,'date' => '03/10/2017'],
        5 => ['id' =>6,'date' => '04/10/2017'],
        6 => ['id' =>7,'date' => '05/10/2017'],
        7 => ['id' =>8,'date' => '01/10/2017']
    ];
```

Html code :

```
<table>
<?php foreach($daterange as $key=>$day)
{ 
?>
<tr>
<td>

    <?php foreach($job as $jdata){
    if(($day->format('Y-m-d') == ($jdata->date)) {
    ?>
    <input type="radio" checked class="radio-check" name="date" value="">
    <?php
    } else {
    ?>
    <input type="radio"  class="radio-check" name="date" value="">
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</td>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>
</table>
```

But `tr` tag is displayed 8 times based on second array count.

How do I display `tr` 5 times, which is the count of the first array, and compare the date inside with the second array?

Comment: From this code, I think you are actually printing 40 non checked inputs (5 `tr` with 8 `input` each one).

Comment: @nanocv: yeah how do I avoid this?

Comment: Your second array is missing some thing, copy and paste it to your editor you will see.

Comment: @GulmuhammadAkbari: but the count first array is always less than the second array. In that scenario, how do I do this?

Comment: Question is not clear. Do you want to display only one `input` inside each `tr`?

Comment: @nanocv: yes I want to display only one input inside `tr` tag and if the date matches I need to make that `input` is checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need one loop for this task and you shouldn't repeat whole lines when you are only modifying a single attribute in the line (as a matter of DRYness).

`array_column()` will sufficiently prepare the `$job` data.

This is what I recommend: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e0e8eaaf9124f8bb823724dea75c04e2227433c3))

```
$daterange = ['01/10/2017','02/10/2017','03/10/2017','04/10/2017','05/10/2017'];
$job = [0 => ['id' =>1,'date' => '03/10/2017'],
        1 => ['id' =>2,'date' => '12/10/2017'],
        2 => ['id' =>3,'date' => '14/10/2017'],
        3 => ['id' =>4,'date' => '13/10/2017'],
        4 => ['id' =>5,'date' => '03/10/2017'],
        5 => ['id' =>6,'date' => '04/10/2017'],
        6 => ['id' =>7,'date' => '05/10/2017'],
        7 => ['id' =>8,'date' => '01/10/2017']
    ];
$job_dates=array_column($job,'date');  // generate 1-dimensional array of dates

echo '<table>';
    foreach($daterange as $date){
        echo "<tr><td><input type=\"radio\" class=\"radio-check\" name=\"date\" value=\"$date\"",(in_array($date,$job_dates)?' checked':''),'></td></tr>';
    }
echo "</table>";

/* or write it over several lines like this:
    echo '<table>';
    foreach($daterange as $date){
        echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>';
                echo "<input type=\"radio\" class=\"radio-check\" name=\"date\" value=\"$date\"";
                if (in_array($date,$job_dates)){
                    echo ' checked';
                }
                echo '>';
            echo '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    echo "</table>";
*/
```

Output:

```
<table>
    <tr><td><input type="radio" class="radio-check" name="date" value="01/10/2017" checked></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="radio" class="radio-check" name="date" value="02/10/2017"></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="radio" class="radio-check" name="date" value="03/10/2017" checked></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="radio" class="radio-check" name="date" value="04/10/2017" checked></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="radio" class="radio-check" name="date" value="05/10/2017" checked></td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

So I created a function `searchForDate` that would check if the date exist in the second array or not, try the below code and here is the [demo](https://eval.in/842443):

```
<?php
$daterange = ['01/10/2017','02/10/2017','03/10/2017','04/10/2017','05/10/2017'];
<table>
    <?php foreach($daterange as $key=>$day)
{ 
?>
<tr>
    <td>
        <?php foreach($daterange as $key=>$day){ 
    if(searchForId($day)) {
        ?>
        <input type="radio" checked class="radio-check" name="date" value="">
        <?php    } else {
        ?>
        <input type="radio"  class="radio-check" name="date" value="">
        <?php    } ?>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
<?php
 function searchForId($day) {
     $job = [
         0 => ['id' =>1,'date' => '03/10/2017' ],
         1 => ['id' =>2,'date' => '12/10/2017'],
         2 => ['id' =>3,'date' => '14/10/2017'],
         3 => ['id' =>4,'date' => '13/10/2017'],
         4 => ['id' =>5,'date' => '03/10/2017'],
         5 => ['id' =>6,'date' => '04/10/2017'],
         6 => ['id' =>7,'date' => '05/10/2017'],
         7 => ['id' =>8,'date' => '01/10/2017']
     ];
     foreach ($job as $key => $val) {
         if ($val['date'] === $day) {
             return $key;
         }
     }
     return null;
 }
?>
```

Comment: how do I do this in view?

Comment: I have updated with entire code. Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Here you have my solution, very similar to yours.

I tried it and it works ok.

```
<?php


$daterange = ['01/10/2017', '02/10/2017', '03/10/2017', '04/10/2017', '05/10/2017'];

$job = [0 => ['id' => 1, 'date' => '03/10/2017'],
    1 => ['id' => 2, 'date' => '12/10/2017'],
    2 => ['id' => 3, 'date' => '14/10/2017'],
    3 => ['id' => 4, 'date' => '13/10/2017'],
    4 => ['id' => 5, 'date' => '03/10/2017'],
    5 => ['id' => 6, 'date' => '04/10/2017'],
    6 => ['id' => 7, 'date' => '05/10/2017'],
    7 => ['id' => 8, 'date' => '01/10/2017']
]

?>

<table>
    <?php
    foreach ($daterange as $day) {
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <?php

                $i = 0;
                $numJobs = count($job);
                $dateFound = 0;

                while ($i < $numJobs && !$dateFound) {
                    if ($job[$i]['date'] == $day) {
                        $dateFound = 1;
                    }
                    $i++;
                }

                if ($dateFound) {
                    ?>
                    <input type="radio" checked class="radio-check" name="date" value="">
                    <?php
                } else {
                    ?>
                    <input type="radio" class="radio-check" name="date" value="">
                    <?php
                }
                ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
</table>
```

Inside each element of `$daterange` I look for that date inside `$job` array with a while loop. If I found it, it stops searching and displays the checked input. Else, if it goes through all the array and doesn't find that date, it displays the non checked input.

(You can just copy and paste it in your code)

Answer (score -1):

```
$job = [0 => ['id' =>1,'date' => '03/10/2017'/* ' here*/ ],
    1 => ['id' =>2,'date' => '12/10/2017'],
    2 => ['id' =>3,'date' => '14/10/2017'],
    3 => ['id' =>4,'date' => '13/10/2017'],
    4 => ['id' =>5,'date' => '03/10/2017'],
    5 => ['id' =>6,'date' => '04/10/2017'],
    6 => ['id' =>7,'date' => '05/10/2017'],
    7 => ['id' =>8,'date' => '01/10/2017']
]
```

Comment: Can you explain how this may solve OP's problem. It fixes a mistake in the code not shows how to solve the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Try this as your for loop.

```
<table>   
    <?php
    foreach ($job as $key => $jdata) {
        if (in_array($jdata['date'], $daterange)) {
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" checked class="radio-check" name="date" value="">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <?php
        }
    }
    ?>
</table>
```